# Why doesn't R throw an error when I use only the initial part of my column name in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

I have a data frame containing various columns along with `sender_bank_flag`. I ran the below two queries on my data frame.

`sum(s_50k_sample$sender_bank_flag, na.rm=TRUE)`

`sum(s_50k_sample$sender_bank, na.rm=TRUE)`

I got the same output from both the queries even though there is no such column as `sender_bank` in my data frame. I expected to get an error for the second code. Didn't know R has such a functionality! Does anyone know what exactly is this functionality and how can it be better utilized?

Comment: This is because of partial matching behind `$`. See `?Extract`. Try `s_50k_sample[["sender_bank_flag"]]` and `s_50k_sample[["sender_bank"]]`

Comment: 李哲源 , please post this as an answer.  `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)` might be of interest as well ...

Comment: More info in Advanced R [chapter on subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators) especially the part with the $ sign and here in the [R language definition 3.4](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) and this [argument matching post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153904/partial-matching-of-function-argument#14155259) on SO. Though this last one is more about the matching for function names.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot to both of you. Really helpful.
PS: Just had a look on this today, hence the delayed reply! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably worthwhile to augment all comments into an answer.

---

Both [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056962/why-didnt-r-throw-error-when-i-used-only-the-initial-part-of-my-column-name-in#comment91064199_52056962) and [BenBolker's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056962/why-didnt-r-throw-error-when-i-used-only-the-initial-part-of-my-column-name-in#comment91066720_52056962) point to doc page `?Extract`:

Under ***Recursive (list-like) objects:***

> Both `"[["` and `"$"` select a single element of the list. [The main difference is that `"$"` does not allow computed indices, whereas `"[["` does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/4891738). `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`.  Also, the partial matching behavior of `"[["` can be controlled using the `exact` argument.

Under ***Character indices:***

> Character indices can in some circumstances be partially matched (see `?pmatch`) to the names or dimnames of the object being subsetted (but never for subassignment).  Unlike S (Becker *et al* p. 358), R **never** uses partial matching when extracting by `"["`, and partial matching is not by default used by `"[["` (see argument `exact`).
>
> Thus the default behaviour is to use partial matching only when extracting from [recursive objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22436994/4891738) (except environments) by `"$"`. Even in that case, warnings can be switched on by `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)`.

Note, the manual has rich information, and make sure you fully digest them. I formatted the content, adding Stack Overflow threads behind where relevant.

---

Links provided by [phiver's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056962/why-didnt-r-throw-error-when-i-used-only-the-initial-part-of-my-column-name-in#comment91068564_52056962) are worth reading in a long term.